# fadeOut fails for part of the selected html (jquery)

Tags: jquery, effects, fadeout

I'm using the fadeOut() and fadeIn() functions to exchange 1 block of html for another. Once I fade in the second block of html, I remove the first block from the DOM.

```
//Fade out the first view, fadein the second, then remove the first from the DOM
$("#courses_body").children(":first-child").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    var that = this;
    courses.fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $(that).remove();
    });
});
```

The trouble I'm having is with the fadeOut() effect. *Part* of the selected html (the header) fades out properly, but the rest of it just waits until the end of the effect and pops off the page (i.e. it disappears instantaneously). Why is it that part of my selection fails to fade out?

EDIT in response to comments:

Here's some of the code that I'm trying but failing to fadeOut:

```
        <span class="day_body"><%= course.day %></span>
        <span class="time_body"><%= course.time %></span>           
        <span class="units_body"><%= course.units_alt %></span>
        <span class="limitations_body"><%= course.limitations %></span>
        <span class="exam_body"><%= course.exam_type %></span>
        <span class="paper_body"><%= course.paper_type %></span>
```

In my css, I've set them all to display:inline-block, so they should be amenable to fading out.

Edit #2: Just tested these spans within the console, and they do indeed fade out when I just call them directly.

Comment: Not all types of HTML elements can be faded. Can you share the rest of your code?

Comment: not a problem with this code. http://jsfiddle.net/5HRDa/

Comment: Is the part of 'courses' that pops in a table? Elements that aren't display: block or display: inline by default can't be faded in.